# Is the condition $\;P(X^2>1|X>0)\;$ the same as $\;P(X>1)\;$?

Tags: probability

I saw two examples for this question the condition $\;X>0\;$ means that $\;X^2>1\;$ is true only when $\;X>1\;$, and the probability is $\;P(X^2>1|X>0)=P(X>1)\;$

But I also saw the same question solved directly by formula

$$P(X^2>1|X>0)=\frac{P(X^2>1\cap X>0)}{P(X>0)}=\frac{P(X>1)}{P(X>0)}$$

I think second method is correct, but first method makes wonder whether the condition is already contained in the calculation.

So what is the correct one?

Comment: I agree the second method is correct.

Comment: Were the ranges for $X$ defined differently in those two examples? If in the first, the range of $X$ only includes positive numbers and in the second it includes negative ones as well, then both are correct in their specific example. Only the second one is correct in general, and if the range of $X$ are positive numbers only, then $P(X >0) = 1$ and then $\frac{P(X > 1) }{P(X >0)} = P(X>1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid, but in the first method, it is still under the condition $X>0$ that you have equivalence, so it should read $P(X^2>1|X>0)=P(X>1|X>0)$.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're asking about "conditions", but then you talk about probabilities. Not the same thing.

It's clear that $X>1$ if and only if $X^2>1$ and $X>0$. So, since equal sets have equal probabilities, $$P(X^2> 1\text{ and } X>0)=P(X>1).$$

But where you make you error is that $P(X^2> 1\text{ and } X>0)$ is not the same thing as $P(X^2> 1| X>0)$. The second is not the probability that $X^2>1$ and $X>0$, it is the probability that $X^2>1$ *given that* $X>0$.

**Example** Say $P(X=2)=P(X=-2)=1/2$ Then the probability that $X>1$ is $1/2$, the same as the probability that $X^2>1$ and $X>0$. But the conditional probability that $X^2>1$ *given* that $X>0$ is $1$.

Comment: Thank you for this response, it is very helpful but I can not give an up arrow because it says I don't have 15 points. Sorry.